# How to efficiently scale all elements in a WinUI 3 desktop app when Window size changes?

Tags: c#, xaml, resize, scale, winui-3

I'd like to have everything in my `WinUI 3` (v1.2) desktop app UI (`MainWindow`) scale up in size as the `MainWindow` changes in size. I'd also like to maintain the relative positioning of everything in the `MainWindow`. The purpose is to allow elderly users a quick and easy way to "enlarge" content by simply expanding the size of the window.

For example, take a vanilla `Template Studio` `WinUI 3` desktop app with menu bar style navigation and a single page (call it `MainPage`). Replace `MainPage.xaml` with

```xaml
<Page
    x:Class="TestScale.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <Border x:Name="Border" Width="300" Height="200" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="The quick brown fox." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

which just draws a red rectangle with a `TextBlock` in the middle of the page (ignoring space used by `ShellPage.xaml`).

I'd like a straightforward way to scale everything, if possible, so that the rectangle and text increase in size (`x` and `y`) in the same proportions (`dx` and `dy`) that `MainPage` does when `MainWindow` changes, but also maintain their relative positions in the `xy` plane. I've tried using `Scale` and various `Translation`s, but it always seems certain elements respond differently or only one dimension responds while the other stays fixed.

For example, adding

```xaml
    Scale="{x:Bind ((app:App)app:App.Current).ScaleToInitialSize, Mode=OneWay}"
```

to the definition of `ShellPage.xaml` almost does the trick except the position of the rectangle changes because the actual size of `MainPage` changes to reflect pixels used but the rectangle size reflects "scaled" sizes.

Is there a good discussion of scaling in `WinUI 3` or `UWP` I've missed? I currently achieve this by binding everything to a `Ratio` property (`Vector2` or `Size`) in my `App` class that changes whenever `MainWindow.SizeChanged` fires. Unfortunately, this means I also have to bind things like XAML `Thickness`, `FontSize`, and even `CornerRadius` properties to maintain the look and layout of the UI.

I expect this is a noob question but I can't seem to find any discussion anywhere. Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-22621). The ViewBox scales its content automatically.

```xml
<Viewbox>
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <Border
            x:Name="Border"
            Width="300"
            Height="200"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="The quick brown fox." />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```